# How to virtualize a file for a single program?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have an application that accesses the /etc/hostname file.
This application is meant to be executed 1 instance per machine.
However, for debugging purposes, I'm running several instances in the same machine.

Therefore, I would like to have a diferente /etc/hostname (and perhaps other files) diferente for each one without having to mannually change the code to look for those files on different paths.

Running each instance in a container is not a feasable option since the application is leveraging a raw socket over a wireless interface (Is it even possible to give direct acess to the interface to a container?)

I only prented to "trick" each instance of the application to access diferente files when acessing the same real file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`firejail`](https://firejail.wordpress.com/).

> Firejail is a SUID program that reduces the risk of security breaches by restricting the running environment of untrusted applications using Linux namespaces and seccomp-bpf. It allows a process and all its descendants to have their own private view of the globally shared kernel resources, such as the network stack, process table, mount table.

Example:

```
# cat /etc/hostname
myhost
# firejail --noprofile --quiet --writable-etc --bind=/etc/timezone,/etc/hostname cat /etc/hostname
Europe/Warsaw
```

You will probably want to define few profiles to easily run several instances of the application. Study `man 1 firejail` and `man 5 firejail-profile`.